# Performing analytics on access.log with Bash

Tags: performance, bash

Before I learned that [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) was a thing, I wanted an analytics solution that I could use locally on my web server. My solution was to write a bash script that would give me some basic info on how my blog is doing. What it attempts to do is to:

1. Find all views of a given page (as determined by lines in the `access.log`)
2. Filter out all bots and crawlers
3. Filter myself out (as I tend to look over my own site quite often)
4. Determine some counts based off the remaining number of lines

What I'm curious about is: are there any faulty assumptions, and are there any glaring inefficiencies in this process?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize some values
PAGE="$1"
LOG="/var/log/apache2/home-site/access.log"
# Words in user agents that hint that the page view is not a person
BOTS=("bot" "facebookexternalhit" "crawler")
# There are other filtered IP's but I've removed them for privacy reasons
FILTERED_IPS=("$(curl -s https://icanhazip.com)")

# Most pages that I care about are <url>/blog/<post name>
# But not all of them are
if [ "${PAGE:0:1}" != "/" ]
then
    PAGE="/blog/$PAGE"
fi
echo "$PAGE"

# Get all views for our page
BLOG_VIEWS=$(grep -a "GET $PAGE" $LOG)
BLOG_VIEW_COUNT=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS" | wc -l)
BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED="$BLOG_VIEWS"

# Clear out the bots
for BOT in "${BOTS[@]}"
do
        TEMP=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED" | grep -avi "$BOT")
        BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED="$TEMP"
done

# Clear out any filtered IP addresses
#   Usually their just me
for IP in "${FILTERED_IPS[@]}"
do
        TEMP=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED" | grep -av "$IP")
        BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED="$TEMP"
done

TOTAL_VIEWS=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED" | wc -l)
UNIQUE_IPS=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED" | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
UNIQUE_IP_COUNT=$(echo "$UNIQUE_IPS" | wc -l)

echo "Total Legitimate Views: $TOTAL_VIEWS"
echo "Legitimate View Percentage:" $( echo "printf('%.2f', ($TOTAL_VIEWS/$BLOG_VIEW_COUNT) * 100)" | perl)
echo "Across $UNIQUE_IP_COUNT unique IP addresses"
```

An example of use looks like the following

```bash
:~$ .scripts/analytics hello-world
/blog/hello-world
Total Legitimate Views: 64
Legitimate View Percentage: 47.06
Across 36 unique IP addresses
```

Answer (score 3):

This script is not *too* long,
but it's getting long enough that you
really ought to be looking for opportunities
to break out helper functions.

---

You have a pair of `for` loops.

```
for BOT in "${BOTS[@]}"
...
for IP in "${FILTERED_IPS[@]}"
```

Each would make a lovely helper function.

Running `grep -v` N times is *one* way
to remove N patterns from the input.
Consider building up a big regex with N elements,
e.g. `grep -v "bot|facebookexternalhit|crawler"`,
to save on repeated reads of a bunch of log entries.

It is unclear why you specified `--binary-files=text`
(`grep -a`). It merits at least a `# comment`,
and maybe in a separate file a unit test that
demonstrates what effect it has.

The grep filtering here is done at a rather coarse level.
Consider handing the regex to `awk` instead,
so that you can match a specific field in the log line.
This prevents spurious matches on strings
like `GET /blog/a-tale-of-two-bots.html`.

---

```
UNIQUE_IPS=$(echo "$BLOG_VIEWS_FILTERED" | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
UNIQUE_IP_COUNT=$(echo "$UNIQUE_IPS" | wc -l)
```

Given that we discard UNIQUE_IPS, consider putting `wc`
in that same pipeline, right after `uniq`.

---

```
echo "Legitimate View Percentage:" $( echo "printf('%.2f', ($TOTAL_VIEWS/$BLOG_VIEW_COUNT) * 100)" | perl)
```

There are many things in this script that we
might have pressed `perl` into service for.
But this one seems odd, given that `bash`
can do arithmetic and format numbers,
or use /usr/bin/printf or the builtin `printf`.
This seems a bit heavyweight.

Also: div by zero?
Maybe append a single blog view line to avoid that?